# Computing a limit involving $n^{1/n}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Evaluate the limit 
>   $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n(n^{1/n}-1)}{\ln (n+2)! - \ln n!}.$$

Clearly the denominator is equivalent to $\ln (n+2) + \ln (n+1)$. I know $n$ alone is stronger than the $\ln$ at the denominator, but what about the sequence $n^{1/n}$? Given it goes to $1$ when $n \to \infty$, what can I say about $n(n^{1/n}-1)$?

Any idea would be useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint. Recall that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}=1$. Therefore, since $\ln(n)/n\to 0$, it follows that
$$\frac{n(n^{1/n}-1)}{\ln(n)}=\frac{\exp(\ln(n)/n)-1}{\ln(n)/n}\to 1.$$
Hence
$$\frac{n(n^{1/n}-1)}{\ln (n+2)! - \ln n!}
=\frac{n(n^{1/n}-1)}{\ln(n)}\cdot  \frac{\ln(n)}{\ln (n+2) + \ln (n+1)}.$$
Can you take it from here?